# Adobe Flash or After Effects: How to make a piece of virtual paper blow away?

Tags: flash, adobe, effects, papervision3d

About a month ago I saw a portfolio website in Flash that featured a stack of cards, and each time you clicked on it, they sort of blew all over the place, thus exposing the backs as videos and pictures.

Although I could easily take a bunch of 3D planes and tween them to turn and flip, these cards actually seemed to 'bend'.

How is this effect achieved?

Sorry I don't have the link to the example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you're talking about probably used a 3D engine like [papervision](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) or [away3d](http://away3d.com/) along with [as3dmod](http://code.google.com/p/as3dmod/), which is a cross-engine library used for modifying the structure of your 3d object. [Here's an example](http://companybrochure.powerflasher.com/).

Comment: Very useful and I'll certainly look into that (and thanks for the quick response!), but I somehow feel like what I'm referring to didn't actually use code and was only a pre-defined animation movie clip brought into Flash. Perhaps I should have asked what programs would allow me to make a movieclip like this.

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation, perhaps you're right about as3dmod.

Thanks again.